# Translate str to int in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have one column like this:

```
day
2018-10-30
2018-9-25
2018-9-30
```

I want to translate day to int day like this:

```
intday
20181030
2018925
2018930
```

Here is my code:

```
f = lambda x : int(x[0]) * 10000 + int(x[1]) * 100 + int(x[2])
train_df['intday'] = train_df['day'].apply([f(x) for x in train_df['day'].str.split('-')])
```

But it's not work, how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What i recommend

```
pd.to_datetime(df.day).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
Out[56]: 
0    20181030
1    20180925
2    20180930
Name: day, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just remove your `-` using `str.replace`, then cast to int:

```
train_df['intday'] = train_df['day'].str.replace('-','').astype(int)

>>> train_df
          day    intday
0  2018-10-30  20181030
1   2018-9-25   2018925
2   2018-9-30   2018930
```